# RESTful web services using jQuery ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, jax-rs

I am using restful web services using java

```
@Path("/data")
public class StudentDataService {

    StudentInfo st=new StudentInfo();

    @GET
    @Path("/mydata")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public List<Student> findAll() {
        System.out.println("data returned to the web service");
        return st.populateData();
    }
}
```

I am returning a list of data containing student name,id,marks, etc.

trying to call this method with jQuery ajax as follows:

```
function findAll() {
console.log('findAll');
 $.ajax({  
       type: "GET",  
       url: "http://localhost:9297/StudentData/rest/data/mydata",  
       dataType: "json",  
       crossDomain: true,
       success: function(resp){  
         // we have the response  
         alert("Data\n '" + resp + "'");  
       },  
       error: function(e){  
         alert('Error: ' + e);  
       }  
     });
}
```

I am getting error

[image]

also it is giving error on console like "no elements found"

Comment: use relative url for ajax.

Comment: Just a guess: instead dataType: "json" try dataType: "application/json". If this does not work please tell us what error message is...

Comment: Your assumption about the argument to the `error` function is incorrect. It is actually the xhr object. Change the function as follows `function(jqxhr, status, errorMsg)`, and alert the status and error message, then report back to us. My initial guess would be you have a cross domain problem

Comment: changed dataType to application/json, and also changed it to    function(jqxhr, status, errorMsg) giving 'Error:parseerror'

Comment: Ok, so you are not returning JSON (like [{"id": "1", "grade": "10"}, {"id": "2", "grade": "9"}] ). Try "text/plain" in ajax and WS and then try if ajax call is successful. If it is, you must fix your WS to return data in correct JSON format.

Comment: it is giving "Error:error"

Comment: As a side note: Your code is not thread safe.

Comment: returning list containg objects of student.

Comment: get the `jqhxr.statusText` and `jqhxr.status` and let us know both

Comment: Also are there any exceptions on the server side?

Comment: getting exception:                                           javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<dao.Student>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

Comment: Are you able to get json data on clicking `http://localhost:9297/StudentData/rest/data/mydata`? Also check the console (F12) for cross site request error.

Comment: OK now we're getting somewhere. You seem to be missing a JSON provider. Are you using Maven?

Comment: show your imports in `StudentDataService` class...and try to post [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: if I set List as return type then it is giving 500 internal server error and with String return type it returning the list with   http://localhost:9297/StudentData/rest/data/mydata

Comment: Make sure you have a JSON provider to handle the serilzation of the `List<Student>` to JSON. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29621030/2587435). Add that then see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "getting exception: `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<dao.Student>, and MIME media type application/json was not found"`"

You seem to missing a JSON provider. If you are using Maven, you can add this dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven, go look for these jars

[image]

You can search for and download all the jars [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider)

Then you can register the provider, by adding the Jackson package to your packages to scan (in your web.xml configuration)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            your.packages.to.scan,
            com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javax.ws.rs.core.Response object and build the output. Else have your own wrapper class and wrap your output and return the wrapper class back to response.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use gson for working with json on server side, because it's very easy to use. For example:

```
List<Student> items = new ArrayList<>();
while (...) {
  items.add(new Student(...));
}
Gson gson = new Gson();
return gson.toJson(items);
```

This is just an example, adopt this to your requirements.

Comment: what should be the return type of function?

Comment: I think it can be String + @Produces("application/json").

Comment: instead of using json if I return String then what dataType should be used in ajax call?

Comment: You return JSON - @Produces("application/json"). So dataType remains "application/json". You could also use @Produces("text/plain") and dataType "text/plain" and then parse return data like JSON.parse(resp) on success...

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a [cors](/questions/tagged/cors) issue. Since you're trying to get type application/json back from the server and your request is crossDomain. If you wrap your jax-rs method with a Response object like @user1129947 suggested, you can modify the headers of the response to allow a cross-origin request like so:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/data")
public class StudentDataService {

    StudentInfo st=new StudentInfo();

    @GET
    @Path("/mydata")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response findAll() {
        return Response.ok(st.populateData())
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .build();
    }
}
```

The header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` will now be on the response which will tell the browser that it is allowed to receive application/json data.

**Please be aware that the * parameter in the header allows any domain to access this resource**

If you want to be sure that only your domains can access this resource then you must set the value of the header to a specific domain.

If you use custom headers or you end up wanting to send cookies to the server then you'll have to deal with preflighted requests which is beyond the scope of this answer.

[See Mozilla's documentation on CORS for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

**Bonus Edit:**

For anyone using CDI with JAX-RS you can check out [this filter-interceptor combo](https://gist.github.com/BrainBacon/667e09373ae1992fcd59) for dealing with CORS

Comment: If it _is_ a CORS issue (which I don't think it is, based on the exception presented in the comments above), your solution would not work, as the preflight is an OPTIONS request. For CORS support, best thing to do would be to implement the headers in a response filter.

Comment: @peeskillet In this case the OPTIONS preflight would not happen unless he is sending a custom request header. Since it's a GET request there's also no request body, so the case where preflight happens because of request body content-type does not apply. Although the other problems with his message-body-writer still apply.

Comment: I forgot it's a GET request :-)

Comment: To expand on @Peskillet's comment, It is best to implement these headers in a ContainerResponseFilter. For those using [tag:CDI] it's possible to write a CrossDomain interceptor that modifies Response objects and adds the necessary headers. In my own setup I use a combination where the OPTIONS preflight is handled by a filter and the headers for the actual response are handled by the interceptor so I can be selective about which jax-rs methods are allowed to be cross-domain.